# Automate creating an image pyramid store with Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

Geoserver has a REST API to automate Geoserver commands, however I do not see any examples of how to automatically create an Image Pyramid store and associated layer. Is that possible? Can anyone provide me sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create pyramid with gdaladdo, you not create pyramid with geoserver. Here is documentation of it
https://gdal.org/gdaladdo.html